# How can I render a GSP as a String?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-2.0

For my email newsletter I need to render a GSP (the HTML for the newsletter) as a `String`, so I  can pass it to my email method. I’ve found many solutions here on Stack Overflow, but I don't know which one would be the best to use with Grails 2.2 (the most recent version).

So what’s your opinion? How would you render a GSP as a `String` without rendering it to the HTTP response?

Thanks and best regards.

Patrick

Comment: As an FYI, render doesn't render "to an http response".  It's the return of the action that writes out to the response.  doelleri's answer is what you're looking for, however.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Grails 2.x, you can inject a `groovyPageRenderer` into a service. This allows you to render any view or template you want via its `render()` method.

For more information, check out [this nice post from Mr. Haki](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2012/03/grails-goodness-render-gsp-views-and.html).

Also note that if you’re using the [Mail plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/mail), you can [use a view for your email body](http://gpc.github.com/grails-mail/docs/guide/3.%20Sending%20Email.html#3.2%20Message%20Content).

Comment: @HikaruShindo Yes it works the same way in a controller.

Comment: Just a note that this still works in Grails 3.0.x (and likely future versions as well).