# How to render view into string in controller?

Tags: grails

Is it possible in grails to render view into string in controller?

I found the similar question ([How can I render a GSP as a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218133/how-can-i-render-a-gsp-as-a-string)) and the suggestion is **"grails.gsp.PageRenderer"**.

So, I try it in controller

```
import grails.gsp.PageRenderer

def getSomething(){
    PageRenderer groovyPageRenderer
    def x = groovyPageRenderer.render((view: 'report', model : [foo : 'bar'])
}
```

It told me "**Cannot invoke method render() on null object**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this...

```
import grails.gsp.PageRenderer

class SomeController {
    def getSomething(){
        PageRenderer groovyPageRenderer
        def x = groovyPageRenderer.render((view: 'report', model : [foo : 'bar'])
    }
}
```

Try this...

```
import grails.gsp.PageRenderer

class SomeController {
    PageRenderer groovyPageRenderer
    def getSomething(){
        def x = groovyPageRenderer.render(view: 'report', model : [foo : 'bar'])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer suggested by Jeff didn't work for me. I used this suggested in this page. https://snipplr.com/view/10815/grails-render-template-as-string/

```
        def x = g.render(template:"mytemplate",model:[name:"myobject"]);
```