# How can I render gson view as a String in grails 3?

Tags: grails, grails3

In grails 2, we can inject a `groovyPageRenderer` into a service or controller and render a GSP into a string as mentioned in [How can I render a GSP as a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218133/how-can-i-render-a-gsp-as-a-string).

For grails 3 rest-api profile, how do we render a gson view into a string?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it is in the documentation

http://views.grails.org/latest/#_the_jsontemplateengine

```
@Autowired
JsonViewTemplateEngine templateEngine
void myMethod() {
        Template t = templateEngine.resolveTemplate('/book/show')
        def writable = t.make(book: new Book(title:"The Stand"))
        def sw = new StringWriter()
        writable.writeTo( sw )
        ...
}
```